# How can I get the "!" as an item on this split list?

Tags: python, regex, split

This is my first question!

What should the pattern be in order to make the last "!" appear as an item on this split list?

```py
    import re
    re.split(r'([.?!]) ', 'One sentence. Another one? And the last one!')
```

I get: `['One sentence', '.', 'Another one', '?', 'And the last one!']`, or `['One sentence', '.', 'Another one', '?', 'And the last one', '!', '']` if I use `([.?!]) ?`.
But I'd like to get this list: `['One sentence', '.', 'Another one', '?', 'And the last one', '!']`

Thank you!

Comment: Make the space optional in your regex.

Comment: Remove the space --`([.?!])` --  Or as @lemon mentions make it optional ..

Comment: *Make the space optional* ([.?!] *)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split using the following regex:

```
(?=[\.?!])|(?<=[\.?!] )
```

which will match

- `(?=[\.?!])`: any place which is followed by a punctuation character
- `(?<=[\.?!] )`: any place which comes after a punctuation character + space

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/agH14r/1).

---

Another option is to use a matching operation on all the strings and all the punctuation symbols:

```
[^\.?!]+(?=[\.?!])|[\.?!]
```

This will match two patterns:

- `[^\.?!]+(?=[\.?!])`: any string `[^\.?!]+`, followed by a punctuation symbol `(?=[\.?!])`
- `[\.?!]`: the punctuation symbol

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/NveH5f/1).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when writing the code. I've just corrected it, could you please have a look to it now? Thank you for your time!

Comment: The update on the answer may wrap up your problem now.